# How to loop element between tr and td in table with Vue?

Tags: json, api, vue.js, for-loop, html-table

For an API data, it includes `posts` root item and an array below it. Even one more array is setting inside the first layer array.

```
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "T1",
            "authors": [
                {
                    name: "A"
                },
                {
                    name: "B"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "T2",
            "authors": [
                {
                    name: "C"
                },
                {
                    name: "D"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Want to loop set values in html table in Vue

```
<template>
    <table>
        <tr v-for="(ps, key) in postList" v-if="key == 'posts'">
            <div v-for="p in ps">
                <td>{{ p.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ p.name }}</td>
                <td v-for="a in p.authors">{{ a.name }}</td>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </table>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue"

export default Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return {
      postList: null,
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.$axios.get("/posts").then(response => { this.postList = response.data; });
  },
})
</script>
```

This way can show data, but since using `div` between tr and td, the data didn't display well on the page. Is there a good way to loop them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use template which acts like an invisible wrapper

```
 <template v-for="p in ps"> ...  </template>
```

More better way would be

```
    <table>
        <template v-for="(ps, key) in postList" v-if="key == 'posts'">
            <tr v-for="p in ps">
                <td>{{ p.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ p.name }}</td>
                <td v-for="a in p.authors">{{ a.name }}</td>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </table>
```

Or

```
   <table>
     <template v-if="postList && postList.posts">
        <template v-for="p in postList.posts">
            <tr :key="p.id">
                <td>{{ p.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ p.name }}</td>
                <td v-for="a in p.authors">{{ a.name }}</td>
            </tr>
        </template>
      </template>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Authors in different columns

```
<table>
      <tr
        v-for="(record, recordIndex) in postList.posts"
        :key="recordIndex"
      >
      <td>{{record.id}}</td>
      <td>{{record.title}}</td>
      <td v-for="(author,authorIndex) in record.authors" :key="authorIndex">
        {{author.name}}
      </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

Authors in same column:

```
<table>
      <tr
        v-for="(record, recordIndex) in postList.posts"
        :key="recordIndex"
      >
      <td>{{record.id}}</td>
      <td>{{record.title}}</td>
      <td>
        <template v-for="(author,authorIndex) in record.authors" >
        <span :key="authorIndex">{{author.name}} </span>
        </template>
      </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```